# removing a duplicate number in a numbers array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need a function to trim a specific number to only 1 repetition in a numbers array.

i can only use `.pop`, `.push` `.length` commands.

If I have array i.e `[ 5,4,6,6,8,4,6,6,3,3,6,5,4,8,6,6]` I need to trim the duplicates of the the digit 6 to show only one time, so the result would be -

`[5,4,6,8,4,6,3,3,6,5,4,8,6].`

using only one array.

I have tried to go thru the array with a for loop, and if i find a 6 that comes after another 6 i tried to move all the other elements one step back each time i find a duplicated 6 , `array[i]  = array [i+1]`

I tried looping in a for inside a loop, no luck.

Comment: Post the code that you attempted along with the error/unexpected behaviour in it.

Comment: Can you use sort and create another array?

Comment: no sorting and no other arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop the array and re-assign values in place, by taking care about whether the current value and the next value are effectively the same and the next one is the targeted one.
Other than that, you need to also handle whether you're at the end of array.

Further explanations can directly be found in the snippet below.

As a final side note, the expected output should rather be:

```
[5,4,6,8,4,6,3,3,6,5,4,8,6]
```

instead of

```
[5,4,6,8,4,6,3,3,6,5,3,8,6]
```

since slightly before the last 8, in your input, you have a 4, not a 3.

```js
function trimSpecificNumber(arr, target) {
  // Define a tracker that will update the array in-place.
  var _track = 0;
  // Loop over all the elements in the array.
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // acquire the current and the next value.
    var _curr = arr[i], _next = arr[i+1];
    // If there is no next value, assign the last element of the array.
    if (!_next) arr[_track++] = _curr;
    else {
      // Otherwise, if the current element is not the same of the next one AND the next one actually isn't the searched needle, assign the current index to the current value (in place).
      if (_next === _curr && _next === target) {
         // Silence is golden, skip this one.
      }
      else {
        arr[_track++] = _curr;
      }
    }

  }
  // Finally, assign the new length of the array, so that next elements will be truncated.
  arr.length = _track;
}

var needle = [5,4,6,6,8,4,6,6,3,3,6,5,4,8,6,6];
trimSpecificNumber(needle, 6);
console.log(needle);
```

Comment: Thank you, that's about what I need.

Answer (score 0):

In your case iterate the array with a for loop, and if the current item is not 
the item to dedupe, or is not identical to the previous, add the item to the current `counter`, and increment the `counter`. When the loop ends, change the length of the array to the length of the counter.

```js
function removeSpecificDuplicate(arr, item) {
  let counter = 0;

  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] !== item || arr[i] !== arr[i-1]) arr[counter++] = arr[i];
  }

  arr.length = counter;
}

const arr = [5,4,6,6,8,4,6,6,3,3,6,5,4,8,6,6]

removeSpecificDuplicate(arr, 6);

console.log(arr)
```